# python regex search and findall

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Below is  my code. My understanding is my pattern says you must meet car and pet is oprtion . i.e check for word car and a carpet both .Now re.search match carpet which is fine.But re.finall output should be ['carpet', 'car'], But it is showing me ['pet', ''] .Please let me know where i am incorrect ?

```
import re
string = "carpet and car"
pattern = r'car(pet)?'
print(re.search(pattern, string))
print(re.findall(pattern, string))
```

Here is output of code:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='carpet'>
['pet', '']
```

Comment: If i use pattern = 'car[p]?[e]?[t]?' then i am able to get my answer . ['carpet', 'car'] But i am still not able to understand why pattern = r'car(pet)?'  is not giving me result in re.findall not shoing me   ['carpet', 'car']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
pattern = r'car(?:pet)?'
```

instead. The `?:` makes the group non-capturing (see the [regex syntax docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)) which makes all the difference to [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) as it returns a list of the capturing groups if such are present in your pattern:

```
>>> re.findall(pattern, "carpet and car")
['carpet', 'car']
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is mentioned in `re` [documentation of `findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups**; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. **Empty matches are included in the result**.

If you want the result you expect, use [`finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer).